# How to reduce the size of video in Android?

Tags: android, compression, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I am new to Android .I don't know how to compress the video in android .

Please, suggest me the options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try Intel **INDE** on https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde and 
 **Media Pack** for Android which is a part of INDE, tutorials on
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android- . It has a sample that shows how to use media pack to transcode=recompress video files.

You can set smaller resolution and\or bitrate to output to get smaller file in **ComposerTranscodeCoreActivity.java**

```
protected void setTranscodeParameters(MediaComposer mediaComposer) throws  IOException {

  mediaComposer.addSourceFile(mediaUri1);
  mediaComposer.setTargetFile(dstMediaPath);

  configureVideoEncoder(mediaComposer, videoWidthOut, videoHeightOut);
  configureAudioEncoder(mediaComposer);
}

protected void transcode() throws Exception {

  factory = new AndroidMediaObjectFactory(getApplicationContext());
  mediaComposer = new MediaComposer(factory, progressListener);
  setTranscodeParameters(mediaComposer);
  mediaComposer.start();
}
```

Comment: links in the answer is not working

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, so...I took the video compression code from the [Telegram for android source code](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) and created a sample project for that, here it is:

https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor

Comment: this is very good

Comment: Isn't there a library that's not on an open source license? GPL is way too much to the left

Comment: thanks for link its working like charm!

Comment: FileNotFoundException, ENOENT (No such file or directory).                                                 i got error in FileUtils of line 44 "out = new FileOutputStream(mFile, false);".        Sir please help me

Comment: Hi @Johndahat, this project is a little bit out-dated.

Comment: Sir can you suggest me another library or code.

Comment: I haven't worked with video compression libraries recently.  This is the one I think could work for you: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg